# Create signed URLs for Google Cloud Storage with node.js for direct upload from browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage

**actual testcase code:** https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/google-cloud-signedurl-test-case

I'm trying to add ability for my API to return signed URLs for direct upload to Google Cloud Storage from the client.

Serverside, I'm using the `gcloud` SDK for this:

```
const gcloud = require('gcloud')

const gcs = gcloud.storage({
  projectId: 'my project',
  keyFilename: __dirname + '/path/to/JSON/file.json'
})
const bucket = gcs.bucket('bucket-name')

bucket.file('IMG_2540.png').getSignedUrl({
 action: 'write',
 expires: Date.now() + 60000
}, (error, signedUrl) => {
  if (error == null) {
    console.log(signedUrl)
  }
})
```

Then in the browser I've got an `<input type='file'/>` that I've selected a file with, then I attempt to post it to the URL generated from my server-side script like this:

```
function upload(blobOrFile, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('PUT', url, true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    console.log('DONE!')
  };
  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      console.log((e.loaded / e.total) * 100)
    }
  };

  xhr.send(blobOrFile);
}

// grab the `File` object dropped (which incidentally
// matches the file name used when generating the signed URL 
upload($('[name=file]').files[0], 'URL GENERATED FROM SERVER-SIDE SCRIPT HERE');
```

What happens?

Response is:

```
<Error>
  <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>
<StringToSign>PUT

image/png
1476631908
/bucket-name/IMG_2540.png</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

I've re-downloaded the JSON key file to make sure it's current and has proper permissions to that bucket and I don't get any errors or anything when generating the signed URL.

The clientside code appears to properly initiate an upload (I see progress updates logged out) then I get the 403 error above. Filenames match, content-types seem to match expected values, expiration seems reasonable.

The official SDK generated the URL, so it seems like it'd be ok.

I'm stuck, any help appreciated.

Comment: I know you say content-types seem to match expected. Still, to confirm, when you look at headers sent from browser it is only content-type: image/png ? XHR does this for you, without you needing to setRequestHeader()?

Comment: Thanks @glenschler, but yeah, XHR does this as of version 2,  I believe. Here's the headers: https://cloudup.com/cWxNOTCs_EZ

Comment: updated to include repo with isolated case: https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/google-cloud-signedurl-test-case

Answer (score 6):

As was pointed out by Philip Roberts, aka @LatentFlip on my github repo containing this case, adding a content-type to the signature took care of it.

https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/google-cloud-signedurl-test-case/pull/1/commits/84290918e7b82dd8c1f22ffcd2c7cdc06b08d334

Also, it sounds like the Google folks are going to update docs/error to be a bit more helpful: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/1695

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same issue. I cloned your repo and it doesn't work. Can you help me with this?