# How to restrict access to a file for a bucket on google cloud platform in node js

Tags: node.js, angular, express, google-cloud-storage

Here is my fileUploadService file:

```
import crypto from 'crypto';
var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

uploadFile(req, bucket, next) {
    if (!req.file) {
        return next();
    }
    const gcsname = req.file.originalname;
    const file = bucket.file(gcsname);
    const stream = file.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
            contentType: req.file.mimetype
        }
    });
    stream.on('error', (err) => {
        req.file.cloudStorageError = err;
        next(err);
    });
    /*stream.on('finish', () => {
        req.file.cloudStorageObject = gcsname;
        file.makePublic().then(() => {
            req.file.cloudStoragePublicUrl = this.getPublicUrl(gcsname);
            next();
        });
    });*/
    stream.end(req.file.buffer);
}
```

I have to make the file accessible for only sender and receiver. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Signed URLs are designed for this purpose.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

This SO question has an example of generating a signed URL in node.js

[Create signed URLs for Google Cloud Storage with node.js for direct upload from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072373/create-signed-urls-for-google-cloud-storage-with-node-js-for-direct-upload-from)