# Google Cloud Cloud Function signed url yields 403 SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm getting a 403 SignatureDoesNotMatch error when trying to load a url generated through:

```
file.getSignedUrl({
  expires: moment()
    .add(10, 'minutes')
    .format()
})
```

I've done all the steps outlined [in the example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/generate-thumbnail), including adding a service account token creator to the  App Engine default service account to allow the creation of signed urls:

[image]

---

As an alternative approach to using `admin` via `firebase-functions` I tried downloading service account credentials `service-account-credentials.json` and creating a gcs storage object as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959262/4570112) as such:

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({
  keyFilename: 'service-account-credentials.json',
  projectId: 'project-id',
});

storage.bucket('bucket-id').getFiles({prefix: 'path/to/dir'}).then(files => files.map(file => [same code as above]));
```

However this still generates SignatureDoesNotMatch urls.

---

I've followed the [github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/244) related to the matter but I have not been able to find a viable solution. [The solution listed by Firebase dev owner @mcdonamp in the issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/244#issuecomment-405661688) references using `iam.signBlobRequest` but I don't know where `iam` is defined, I only see it [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/Iam) as a property of `bucket`, with no `signBlobRequest` method, and [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob) as an HTTP API endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that despite [the doc's claim](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.3.x/File#getSignedUrl) of `Content-Type` headers being optional, they are not. As suggested by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072373/create-signed-urls-for-google-cloud-storage-with-node-js-for-direct-upload-from) and [this github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/1695), adding `contentType` to the `getSignedUrl` options argument fixes the issue:

```
file.getSignedUrl({
  action: 'read',
  contentType: 'audio/wav',
  expires: moment()
  .add(10, 'minutes')
  .format()
})
```

Make sure to also include the header when requesting the resource as well.